# d3js: d3.nest - Manipulating data in the DOM

Tags: d3.js

I'm working through making a variation of this [population pyramid by Mike Bostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062085). My data, like his, is a CSV with male/female populations across different "groups" (his are age groups, mine are regions) over many years.

My question relates to how arrays work in the DOM. Initially, after calling my CSV and doing `console.log(dataset)`, my data looks like this:

[image]

That is, for each `round`, I have the `region`, followed by the male and female population numbers. All fine. However, I'm planning to add transitions which move over each `round` (e.g. a bar chart that shows the M/F pops for all regions in round 0, then .on(click) in round 1, etc.). To that end, I followed Mike's lead and used `d3.nest`:

```
          data = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) { return d.region; })
            .key(function(d) { return d.round; })
            .rollup(function(v) { return v.map(function(d) { return d.people; }); })
            .map(data);
```

My data now looks like this in the DOM (`console.log(data)`):

[image]

This also looks good - my data's now organized by `region`, sub-divided into `rounds` (and the male/female pops for those).

And now I'm stuck. I just don't know how to call the data from `data` (as opposed to `dataset`). I'd like to, for example, create some `rect` groups for men/women from each `region` for `round==0`. I'm using Mike's code --

```
        regions.selectAll("rect")
            .data(function(region) { return data[round][region] || [0, 0]; })
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("x", -barWidth / 2)
            .attr("width", barWidth)
            .attr("y", y)
            .attr("height", function(value) { return h - d.people; })
            .attr("fill", "green");
```

-- as a base, and trying variations of `data.arusha[0]` in the JS console, e.g., to see just how to *access* each piece of it. I've gone through some JS tutorials, and understand (well, sort of) that you can access, say, the first piece of an array by something like:

```
var fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Donkey"];
console.log(fruits[0]);
```

But I'm not making much progress. I realize this might be more of a JS/"understanding objects/arrays" questions, so I'll appreciate any help - including references to resources I could work through.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to do?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up your nesting orders -- in your nest function, you are grouping first by region, then by round.  But in your data call, you have them in the reverse order.  [This MDN Guide is a good introduction to Javascript syntax and datatypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide).

Comment: Thanks, Amelia. I'll take a look at the MDN stuff and try to get a handle on d3's data call too (still a weak point for me). Dwayne - ultimately, I'd like to make a bar chart for each `round` of the population per region, which I can transition between using keystrokes.